# Can't upload from my php form to google docs - getting error

Tags: php, zend-framework, google-docs, zend-gdata

Hi guys I'm building a form that uploads documents to my google docs account however its not working I keep getting an error - the following is my code;

```
$service = Zend_Gdata_Docs::AUTH_SERVICE_NAME;
$client = Zend_Gdata_ClientLogin::getHttpClient($username, $pww, $service);
$docs = new Zend_Gdata_Docs($client);

$newDocumentEntry = $docs->uploadFile($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'], $_FILES['file']['name'], null, Zend_Gdata_Docs::DOCUMENTS_LIST_FEED_URI);
```

I get the following error:

> PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught exception 'Zend_Gdata_App_HttpException'
>   with message 'Expected response code 200, got 400 Inconsistent
>   repeating query parameter ' in C:...\Zend\Gdata\App.php:700

I'm using php and the Zend gdata code.

Answer (score 0):

There is a "bug" in Zend_Gdata_Docs with the mimetype.
If you are using a temporary file and the filename as the title it will not auto-magically pull the mimetype for you. It tries to pull the mimetype based on the fileLocation extension which does not exist on a temporary file.

I made a class that works for me, rather than updating the Zend class.
It is called [ConvertDoc](http://blog.artistandesigns.com/2011/02/zendgdata-lacks-document-download.html) because I wanted to be able to [upload a spreadsheet and download as csv.](http://blog.artistandesigns.com/2011/02/zendgdata-lacks-document-download.html)

What you really need is this...

```
    // get mimetype from original file name
    $filenameParts = explode('.', $originalFileName);
    $fileExtension = end($filenameParts);
    $mimeType = Zend_Gdata_Docs::lookupMimeType($fileExtension);
```

And pass the $mimetype instead of null.